# Can appweb have subwebs?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Can we create subwebs in appweb ?

If yes then can we also setup permissions using groups e.g. create new groups in app too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a subsite inside an appweb, Microsoft has restricted it, If you will try to create a Subite in appweb using CSOM you will get an Exception message set by Microsoft that a subsite cannot be created inside appweb